# Dropdown over div borders (div with scroll:auto)

Tags: jquery, css, select, overflow, dropdown

I have a div that needs to be scrollable, if the content gets too long.
Now I have added a select box (which was styled with jQuery Plugin MultipleSelect) to this div. When I open the DropDown, the options get "lost"/are not visible.

```css
    #samplediv {
      overflow: auto;
      max-height: 100px;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="samplediv">
        Lorem ipsum<br/>
        <select class="w300" multiple="multiple">
            <option value="1">January</option>
            <option value="2">February</option>
            <option value="3">March</option>
            <option value="4">April</option>
            <option value="5">May</option>
            <option value="6">June</option>
            <option value="7">July</option>
            <option value="8">August</option>
            <option value="9">September</option>
            <option value="10">October</option>
            <option value="11">November</option>
            <option value="12">December</option>
        </select>
        <br/>dolor sit
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add overflow visible to

```
#samplediv{
    overflow: visible;
    max-height: 100px;
}
```

---

**Correct Answer:**

To solve with the scroll add position absolute to the select box and make a fake space div in order to simulate the space from the select [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RACCH/b3g1tk3w/4/), since this will have a position absolute, simulate the static position with jquery scroll reducing the top attribute while the div is scrolled

Comment: oh wait..... it does show the whole dropdown now, but if the rest of the div content is longer than the 100px max-height it does not show any scrollbars anymore.. Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/SchweizerSchoggi/uz0gbbyf/1/

Comment: Try removing `max-height: 100px;`; Or increasing it as needed.

Comment: Unfortunatly removing or increasing is not possible here. The Div can contain hundreds of lines, but it should only have around 10 of them visible, the rest should be scrollable. Hmm....

Comment: I correct it the answer you can check it on the new fiddle ..unfortunately ther is another problem the select will not scroll since it has an absolute position...

Comment: Thx, but this is definitely a problem, as a select like this appears in each of the x lines in the div, so it cannot keep its position

Comment: Got it , the answer is pudated I have implement this playing with jquery scroll now it should be fixed...

Comment: holy smoke.... it definitely works! Awesome!! Thanks for spending your time on this. I will mark it as solved now.